# Configuration error when installing PLUMED - configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, installation, configure

I was trying to install a software called PLUMED from https://github.com/plumed/plumed2.git. However, I kept having the following error message when executing the command `./configure --prefix=/home/wei-tse/Documents/Software/PLUMED/plumed2_build`:

```
configure: Optional modules are disabled by default
checking for mpic++... mpic++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/wei-tse/Documents/Software/PLUMED/plumed2':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

This is weird because I didn't have this error message when I installed PLUMED for the first time (like a year ago though). I've checked `config.log`  and looked up possible solutions to this problem, but I still have no clue about how to solve this. Could anyone help me with this? `config.log` is attached as below. Thank you so much!!

**The content of `config.log`**:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by PLUMED configure 2, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/home/wei-tse/Documents/Software/PLUMED/plumed2_build

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = castlepeak
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.3.0-40-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #32~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 14:05:59 UTC 2020

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/bin/dssp
PATH: /home/wei-tse/amber18/bin
PATH: /home/wei-tse/Documents/KBD_project
PATH: /home/wei-tse/Documents/Software/openeye/arch/Ubuntu-16.04-x64/quacpac
PATH: /usr/local/bin/dssp
PATH: /home/wei-tse/amber18/bin
PATH: /home/wei-tse/Documents/KBD_project
PATH: /home/wei-tse/Documents/Software/openeye/arch/Ubuntu-16.04-x64/quacpac
PATH: /usr/local/bin/dssp
PATH: /home/wei-tse/amber18/bin
PATH: /home/wei-tse/Documents/KBD_project
PATH: /home/wei-tse/Documents/Software/openeye/arch/Ubuntu-16.04-x64/quacpac
PATH: /usr/local/gromacs/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin/dssp
PATH: /home/wei-tse/amber18/bin
PATH: /home/wei-tse/Documents/KBD_project
PATH: /home/wei-tse/Documents/Software/openeye/arch/Ubuntu-16.04-x64/quacpac
PATH: /usr/local/bin/dssp
PATH: /home/wei-tse/amber18/bin
PATH: /home/wei-tse/Documents/KBD_project
PATH: /home/wei-tse/Documents/Software/openeye/arch/Ubuntu-16.04-x64/quacpac
PATH: /home/wei-tse/.local/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin/dssp
PATH: /home/wei-tse/amber18/bin
PATH: /home/wei-tse/Documents/KBD_project
PATH: /home/wei-tse/Documents/Software/openeye/arch/Ubuntu-16.04-x64/quacpac
PATH: /home/wei-tse/anaconda3/bin
PATH: /home/wei-tse/anaconda3/condabin
PATH: /home/wei-tse/.local/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2424: Optional modules are disabled by default
configure:3366: checking for mpic++
configure:3382: found /home/wei-tse/anaconda3/bin/mpic++
configure:3393: result: mpic++
configure:3420: checking for C++ compiler version
configure:3429: mpic++ --version >&5
/home/wei-tse/anaconda3/bin/mpic++: line 283: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++: command not found
configure:3440: $? = 127
configure:3429: mpic++ -v >&5
mpicxx for MPICH version 3.3.2
/home/wei-tse/anaconda3/bin/mpic++: line 299: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++: command not found
configure:3440: $? = 127
configure:3429: mpic++ -V >&5
/home/wei-tse/anaconda3/bin/mpic++: line 283: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++: command not found
configure:3440: $? = 127
configure:3429: mpic++ -qversion >&5
/home/wei-tse/anaconda3/bin/mpic++: line 283: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++: command not found
configure:3440: $? = 127
configure:3460: checking whether the C++ compiler works
configure:3482: mpic++ -O3   conftest.cpp  >&5
/home/wei-tse/anaconda3/bin/mpic++: line 283: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++: command not found
configure:3486: $? = 127
configure:3524: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "PLUMED"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "plumed"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "PLUMED 2"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3529: error: in `/home/wei-tse/Documents/Software/PLUMED/plumed2':
configure:3531: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_BASH_COMPLETION_DIR_set=
ac_cv_env_BASH_COMPLETION_DIR_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_FCFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FCFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_FC_set=
ac_cv_env_FC_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDSHARED_set=
ac_cv_env_LDSHARED_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_MPIEXEC_set=
ac_cv_env_MPIEXEC_value=
ac_cv_env_PYTHON_BIN_set=
ac_cv_env_PYTHON_BIN_value=
ac_cv_env_SOEXT_set=
ac_cv_env_SOEXT_value=
ac_cv_env_STATIC_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_STATIC_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CXX=mpic++

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR_CR=''
BASH_COMPLETION_DIR=''
CC=''
CFLAGS=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='mpic++'
CXXCPP=''
CXXFLAGS='-O3'
DEFS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FC=''
FCFLAGS=''
GREP=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDSHARED=''
LD_RO=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MPIEXEC=''
OBJEXT=''
OPENMP_CXXFLAGS=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='PLUMED'
PACKAGE_STRING='PLUMED 2'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='plumed'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='2'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PYTHON_BIN=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SOEXT=''
STATIC_LIBS=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX='mpic++'
ac_ct_FC=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
build_dir=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
disable_dependency_tracking=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dot=''
doxygen=''
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
make_doc=''
make_pdfdoc=''
make_static_archive=''
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
pkgconfig_bin=''
prefix='/home/wei-tse/Documents/Software/PLUMED/plumed2_build'
program_can_run=''
program_can_run_mpi=''
program_name=''
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
readelf=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''
use_absolute_soname=''
use_loader_path=''
xxd=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "PLUMED"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "plumed"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "2"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "PLUMED 2"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show OS name, version. ... Your PATH's are looking quite unusual. And : Functional g++, mpic++ is expected ... in /usr/bin. My config.log https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ucnebivpygbsy1/a-plumed2_config.log.txt?dl=0

Comment: Thank you for your reply @KnudLarsen. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I later solved the problem by the command `./configure --prefix=/home/wei-tse/Documents/Software/PLUMED/plumed2_build CXX=g++ CC=gcc`. (I also install `x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++` by `conda install gxx_linux-64`.)